# How to chose a specific field from correct object in JSON schema?

Tags: java, json, validation, testing

I am working with a JSON schema and trying to validate specific field. Normally I specify a path to retrieve a value for validation based on the position of the object in the array as such:

```
mapList.Object[0].memberAmount
```

But in the situation below , the order of the objects changes each time , so I need to chose a field from a specific object from the array. How can I write a path with following logic ? give me a memberAmount field value from the object where the typeID is 23098 (this field value is always unique).That way even if the order of the objects changes in the array, I will still have the correct field value from the correct object.

```
"MapList": {
    "Object": [
        {
            "TypeId": 230098,
            "mIndicator "P",
            "memberAmount": 110.00,
            "edAmount": 0.00,
            "plra": 0.00,
            "spaf": 0.00,
            "grossAmount": 110.00,
        },
        {
            "TypeId": 230099,
            "mIndicator "A",
            "memberAmount": 900.00,
            "edAmount": 0.00,
            "plra": 0.00,
            "spaf": 0.00,
            "grossAmount": 110.00,
        },
        {
            "TypeId": 230100,
            "mIndicator "A",
            "memberAmount": 660.00,
            "edAmount": 0.00,
            "plra": 0.00,
            "spaf": 0.00,
            "grossAmount": 110.00,
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the particular element, you can use `JsonPath.parse()`, which returns a `List<Map<String, Object>>`, which can be traversed to retrieve your target value:

```java
String memberAmount = (String)JsonPath.parse(jsonString)
  .read("$['Object'][?(@['TypeId'] == 230098)]")
  .get(0)
  .get("memberAmount");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider library *Josson* to retrieve value with simple query expression.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"MapList\": {" +
    "        \"Object\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "                \"TypeId\": 230098," +
    "                \"mIndicator\": \"P\"," +
    "                \"memberAmount\": 110.0," +
    "                \"edAmount\": 0.0," +
    "                \"plra\": 0.0," +
    "                \"spaf\": 0.0," +
    "                \"grossAmount\": 110.0" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"TypeId\": 230099," +
    "                \"mIndicator\": \"A\"," +
    "                \"memberAmount\": 900.0," +
    "                \"edAmount\": 0.0," +
    "                \"plra\": 0.0," +
    "                \"spaf\": 0.0," +
    "                \"grossAmount\": 110.0" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"TypeId\": 230100," +
    "                \"mIndicator\": \"A\"," +
    "                \"memberAmount\": 660.0," +
    "                \"edAmount\": 0.0," +
    "                \"plra\": 0.0," +
    "                \"spaf\": 0.0," +
    "                \"grossAmount\": 110.0" +
    "            }" +
    "        ]" +
    "    }" +
    "}");
```

**Query**

```
Double memberAmount = josson.getDouble("MapList.Object[TypeId=230098].memberAmount");
System.out.println(memberAmount);
// Output: 110.0
```